# how to input the values in a file into a bash script in ubuntu

Tags: bash

We have a simple exercise into which we have to get some values from a file and print out the result. The file contains a matrix and we have to do `f=3*x^2 +4*y+5*z` where x y z are the numbers of a 3x3 array that is inputted through a file.
Lets say that i name the matrix file `f1`.
How do i input the value of this file into the bash script

This is what i have done:

```
#!bin/bash/

 while read x y z
do
    let f=3*x*x+4*y+*z;
    echo -n "f"
done < f1
exit 0
```

Comment: shouldn't a 3x3 array have 9 numbers rather than just 3?

Comment: @jhnc I think "array" is a misnomer here and really they want to read the file line-by-line treating each line as a 3-tuple (x, y, z).

Comment: `let` doesn't need dollars but `echo` does: eg. `echo -n "$f"`; `#!bin/bash/` should probably be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: You're actually inputting the values properly, but you're missing the 5 before `z`, which causes a syntax error. I'm voting to close the question as a typo. In the future, please provide any errors you're getting, and try to ask about that specific problem instead of the overall task. See [ask] and [mre]. See also [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Comment: @w we have a 3x3 array and we read it line by line.  The question was. What should i do so that this bash script reads the values from another file. Like how do i input them form the f1 lets say into this

Comment: @Severjan Sorry, why are you telling me the question again? I've already replied to it.

Comment: @wjandrea then since i have inputed them correctly what is the problem? As i said i just recently began with bash script so my knowledge regarding this is quite very limited. can you point out how to fix this?

Comment: @wjandrea yes i apologize. you wrote the comment while i was writing my own

Answer (score 0):

This script shows how to encapsulate an input file definition into the calling script, allowing a variable to be expanded into the resulting file (**${MINE}**).

if you wanted the contents to **include non-expanded variables**, you would **put double quotes** around the first "**EnDoFiNpUt**", on the "**cat**" line, not around the second instance.  That would deposit the exact text into the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

MINE=8

cat >f1 <<EnDoFiNpUt
9 3 6
7 ${MINE} 2
2 1 4
EnDoFiNpUt

while read x y z
do
    let f=3*x*x+4*y+z
    echo -e "\t[${x} ${y} ${z}]   f = ${f}"
done <f1
exit 0
```